Try to compile and install rocket-chip generator but scala reports a constant pool index error
Here is the bug report:
macros.compile scala.reflect.internal.FatalError: 
  bad constant pool index: 0 at pos: 48461
     while compiling: <no file>
        during phase: globalPhase=<no phase>, enteringPhase=<some phase>
     library version: version 2.13.10
    compiler version: version 2.13.10
  reconstructed args: -bootclasspath $HOME/.cache/coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.13.10/scala-library-2.13.10.jar -classpath $HOME/.cache/coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.13.10/scala-reflect-2.13.10.jar:$HOME/verilator-optimization/rocket-chip/macros/compile-resources:$HOME/verilator-optimization/rocket-chip/out/macros/compile.dest/classes

  last tree to typer: EmptyTree
       tree position: <unknown>
            tree tpe: <notype>
              symbol: null
           call site: <none> in <none>

== Source file context for tree position ==


    scala.reflect.internal.Reporting.abort(Reporting.scala:69)
    scala.reflect.internal.Reporting.abort$(Reporting.scala:65)
    scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.abort(SymbolTable.scala:28)
    scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser$ConstantPool.errorBadIndex(ClassfileParser.scala:408)
    scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser$ConstantPool.getExternalName(ClassfileParser.scala:263)
    scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.readParamNames$1(ClassfileParser.scala:842)
    scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parseAttribute$1(ClassfileParser.scala:848)
    scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.$anonfun$parseAttributes$6(ClassfileParser.scala:925)
    scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parseAttributes(ClassfileParser.scala:1497)
    scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parseMethod(ClassfileParser.scala:625)
    scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parseClass(ClassfileParser.scala:548)
    scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.$anonfun$parse$2(ClassfileParser.scala:175)
    scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.$anonfun$parse$1(ClassfileParser.scala:160)
    scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parse(ClassfileParser.scala:143)
    scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$ClassfileLoader.doComplete(SymbolLoaders.scala:342)
    scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$SymbolLoader.$anonfun$complete$2(SymbolLoaders.scala:249)
    scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$SymbolLoader.complete(SymbolLoaders.scala:247)
    scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.completeInfo(Symbols.scala:1563)
    scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.info(Symbols.scala:1535)
    scala.reflect.internal.Definitions.scala$reflect$internal$Definitions$$enterNewMethod(Definitions.scala:48)
    scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.String_$plus$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:1261)
    scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.String_$plus(Definitions.scala:1261)
    scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.syntheticCoreMethods$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:1583)
    scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.syntheticCoreMethods(Definitions.scala:1565)
    scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.symbolsNotPresentInBytecode$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:1596)
    scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.symbolsNotPresentInBytecode(Definitions.scala:1596)
    scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.init(Definitions.scala:1652)
    scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.<init>(Global.scala:1236)
    xsbt.ZincCompiler$ZincRun.<init>(CallbackGlobal.scala:80)
    xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerBridge.scala:161)
    xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerBridge.scala:134)
    xsbt.CompilerBridge.run(CompilerBridge.scala:39)
    sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:91)
    sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.$anonfun$compile$7(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:193)
    scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.scala:18)
    sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.timed(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:248)
    sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.$anonfun$compile$4(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:183)
    sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.$anonfun$compile$4$adapted(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:163)
    sbt.internal.inc.JarUtils$.withPreviousJar(JarUtils.scala:239)
    sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compileScala$1(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:163)
    sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compile(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:211)
    sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileInternal$1(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:534)
    sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileInternal$1$adapted(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:534)
    sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.$anonfun$apply$5(Incremental.scala:180)
    sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.$anonfun$apply$5$adapted(Incremental.scala:178)
    sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$$anon$2.run(Incremental.scala:464)
    sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon$CycleState.next(IncrementalCommon.scala:116)
    sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon$$anon$1.next(IncrementalCommon.scala:56)
    sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon$$anon$1.next(IncrementalCommon.scala:52)
    sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon.cycle(IncrementalCommon.scala:263)
    sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.$anonfun$incrementalCompile$8(Incremental.scala:419)
    sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.withClassfileManager(Incremental.scala:506)
    sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.incrementalCompile(Incremental.scala:406)
    sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.apply(Incremental.scala:172)
    sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compileInternal(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:534)
    sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileIncrementally$1(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:488)
    sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.handleCompilationError(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:332)
    sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:425)
    sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compile(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:137)
    mill.scalalib.worker.ZincWorkerImpl.compileInternal(ZincWorkerImpl.scala:544)
    mill.scalalib.worker.ZincWorkerImpl.$anonfun$compileMixed$1(ZincWorkerImpl.scala:334)
    mill.api.FixSizedCache.withCachedValue(FixSizedCache.scala:66)
    mill.scalalib.worker.ZincWorkerImpl.withCompilers(ZincWorkerImpl.scala:414)
    mill.scalalib.worker.ZincWorkerImpl.compileMixed(ZincWorkerImpl.scala:333)
    mill.scalalib.ScalaModule.$anonfun$compile$2(ScalaModule.scala:280)
    mill.define.Task$TraverseCtx.evaluate(Task.scala:71)

To be honest, I don't familiar with scala, and I just want to use rocket-chip and verilator to do some work about performance optimization. Here is my scala version:
$scala -version
Scala code runner version 3.4.2 -- Copyright 2002-2024, LAMP/EPFL

and the architecture of my cpu is aarch64.
System: Ubuntu22.04

Based on the error message
macros.compile scala.reflect.internal.FatalError: 
  bad constant pool index: 0 at pos: 48461
     while compiling: <no file>
        during phase: globalPhase=<no phase>, enteringPhase=<some phase>
     library version: version 2.13.10 // <-- pay attention here
    compiler version: version 2.13.10
  reconstructed args: -bootclasspath $HOME/.cache/coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.13.10/scala-library-2.13.10.jar -classpath $HOME/.cache/coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.13.10/scala-reflect-2.13.10.jar:$HOME/verilator-optimization/rocket-chip/macros/compile-resources:$HOME/verilator-optimization/rocket-chip/out/macros/compile.dest/classes

and the scala version you have installed
$scala -version
Scala code runner version 3.4.2 -- Copyright 2002-2024, LAMP/EPFL

I would think you installed the wrong version of scala. There is an open issue  at chisel to support for scala 3




Flowdalic on Apr 4




Chisel currently supports Scala 2.12 and Scala 2.13. It would be great if support for Scala 3 would also be available.






jackkoenig on Apr 4




Agreed entirely, there's just a chunk of work to do. I have recently started some baby steps here: https://github.com/chipsalliance/chisel/tree/source-scala-3. Also note that we've dropped Scala 2.12 as of 6.0.0.




For the moment only scala 2.12 (depends on chisel version) and 2.13 are supported. So, you should downgrade the scala version you insalled (3.4.2) to 2.13. How you can do that depends on the steps you followed to install it and what are the commands you are using to execute whatever you are trying to to run.

Thanks very much! However, when I downgrade scala to 2.13.10, it seems that rocket chip still can't be properly constructed. Emmm.. I don't know how can I paste my error log on my comment.

Don't post error code in comments. Edit your post to add more details. Try to add as much details as you can. What were all the steps you followed from the beginning, such as install chisel, install verilog, install rocket-chip, what commands you executed and we're the outputs of each execution

Thanks, It seems that my rocket-tools weren't installed properly. I am trying to figure out what went wrong.

Hello, I just checked my toolchain and found that riscv-test can't be compiled. It reports that:```$HOME/verilator-optimization/riscv/toolchain/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/12.2.0/../../../../riscv64-unknown-elf/bin/ld:$HOME/verilator-optimization/rocket-tools/riscv-tests/build/../isa/../env/v/link.ld:0: syntax error .


That's a different error. It has no direct relation with your original question. You should edit your post detailing how you get there to provide more context. Describe what were the steps you followed to install each tool and what commands were executed with the corresponding outputs. You can also add details about the machine and operative system where you are trying to do this

I've successfully rebuilt my rocket-tools and chisel. However the same question occurred again when I tried building rocket-chip:
[info] compiling 1 Scala source to $HOME/verilator-optimization/rocket-chip/out/macros/compile.dest/classes ...
[error] 
[error]   bad constant pool index: 0 at pos: 48461
[error]      while compiling: <no file>
[error]         during phase: globalPhase=<no phase>, enteringPhase=<some phase>
[error]      library version: version 2.13.10
[error]     compiler version: version 2.13.10


What extra information should I provide?

Edit your post and detail step by step each executed command and the output you got. Also run scala -version to be sure that you are using the right one
